# Adding a block to markup

Tags: blocks

I have created several content types and using views I have created blocks that take the uid as an argument and displays content that that author has created. So far so good.

What I want to do now is create a module that displays all these blocks in a given area,

I have the HTML ready and I can create a page that passes the markup back to drupal and display that, what I would like to do is populate those areas with the given block.

so for example. If I have a page called:

www.example.com/displayMyContent/58 (where 58 is the user ID)

the HTMl of the page would be online these lines:

```
<?php
$uid = args(2);
$markup = "
<div id="myVideoBlock"> ". drupal_call_to_render_block("MyVideosBlock", $uid). "</div>";

?>
```

what would be the function to insert the given block into the given section and how would I pass the $uid to the block so that only the authors content would be displayed?

Also there are reasons why i am not using the blcok functions in admin mainly because there will be other blocks added on the page and I need control of where the blocks will be placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be able to do this by using the global $user variable.

1. 1 create the hooks block_info and block_view
2. create hook_theme()
3. define a theme to be able to pass variables to template.
4. create the template

in your block_view do something along the lines of this:

```
switch($delta){
    case 'myvideoblock':
            global $user;
            $view = views_get_view('YOURVIEW');
            $view->set_display('YOURDISPLAY');
            $view->set_arguments($user->uid);
            $result = $view->execute;
            $your_variable = $result->result;
            $block['content'] = theme('videoblock', array('your_variable' => $your_variable));
}
```

You should poke around in the $result->result object to get to your content though.

Hope this helps

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much this works perfectly!